# MacBook Pro unable to communicate with Apple Watch

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, apple-watch, password

### Apple Watch won't unlock MacBook Pro

Up until yesterday, my MacBook Pro worked just fine with my Apple Watch - I walk up, touch the keyboard or trackpad, Mac unlocks and I get to work. No worries! Yesterday something changed and now my watch won’t unlock my laptop.

I’ve tried everything in the Apple Support post, including repairing my phone/watch, re-establishing two-factor authentication (2FA), and rebooting my laptop, iPhone, and watch. All to no avail. I tried the @Morwen suggestion with Messages because there was a gap in my message history, but that didn't do it.

When I try to enable my watch, I get the error message shown below (albeit after about 6 or 7 minutes later, not quickly like the gif image). My watch, iPhone, and MacBook are all signed in and communicating with Apple.

[image]

The only thing I can think of that might play into this is that I was setting up a personal VPN on my home router last night, but I’ve turned that off as part of my troubleshooting (and couldn’t replicate the issue).

---

Digging a little further, I found this message (repeatedly since yesterday) in my Console logs. It looks like I have two permissions conflicting, but I can't tell which is which, nor where to go to change one of them...

> Oct 21 02:17:54 Johns-MBP
>   com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice[790]: objc[790]: Class
>   AWDSecurityPrefAutoUnlockSetup is implemented in both
>   /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice
>   (0x10d6018e0) and
>   /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Security
>   (0x10fd0b210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

---

Environment includes:

1. 2017 15" MacBook Pro with Mojave (updated)
2. Apple Watch Series 3 with Cellular (updated)

Comment: Do you have any issues with any bluetooth connections on the MBP?  I had this same problem when I updated to Mojave.  Turn off bluetooth on your mac, delete: /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist turn bluetooth back on.  See if that helps.

Comment: @fsb - that totally fixed it! Thanks a bunch, fsb. Can you put it in as an answer so I can select it as the one that resolved my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I updated to Mojave.  These steps solved my problem:

1. Turn off bluetooth on the Mac
2. Open Finder and navigate to `~/Library/Preferences`
3. Delete the file `com.apple.bluetooth.plist`
4. Turn bluetooth back on
5. If `Allow your Apple Watch to unlock your Mac` is off, check the box to turn it on
6. Test if your Watch unlocks the Mac

Comment: Thanks fsb - this totally solved the issue I was having. My MBP is happily unlocking with my Apple Watch again. FWIW, and anybody else that might run into a similar problem, the console log entries that I posted in the original query coincided precisely with my attempts to unlock my computer with my watch; they have stopped since I followed the instructions that fsb gave.

Comment: I don't have a ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.bluetooth.plist

Answer (score 1):

I don't know my solution still works with OP's system - however **unlocking your iPhone** solved the problem for me.